# Keeping the entered text if Vuetify Autocomplete does not have a matching result

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-autocomplete where users be able to search, and I would like to keep the one that's in the v-autocomplete component if there are no matching results. But normal behaviour for a v-autocomplete is to remove what's on the component if there is no matching result.

I have created a method named testBlur() which I call on the blur event for the v-autocomplete component.

Is anybody be able to help me with this?

```
codepen: https://codepen.io/pen/gBWEVB
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you're saving the unmatched text, you could try Combobox with [Advanced custom options](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox).

Comment: see this example I think it will help you  https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox#example-advanced

Comment: Thanks alot guys. I will look into this today and get back to you if I have any additional questions.

Comment: Combo box solved the questions I had. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Combo box solved this issue.

As Gil mentioned you could use a Combo box with Advanced custom options. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox